# Neural network that learns patterns in very large matrices

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

Suppose we have some large matrices that want to classify.

[image]

If matrices are M*N, is it OK to have a neural network with M*N neurons that is, for each element a neuron ? Is there any better idea? Actually, in my case, I have 50 matrices with 200 rows and 200 columns [ 200*200 ].
{The elements of input matrices are 0 and 1 }
Thank you in advance.

Comment: ;-) You are right. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Find a suitable value for the number of hidden nodes, H, by trial and error. 
Create numH*Ntrials plus An outer loop H = Hmin:dH:Hmax over number of hidden nodes and an inner loop i = 1: 
Ntrials over number of random trn/val/tst data divisions and random weight initialization trials for each value of H.